# Python program for word count, average word length, word frequency and frequency of words starting with letters of the alphabet

Tags: python, file, dictionary, python-3.3, word-count

Need to write a Python program that analyzes a file and counts:

- The number of words
- The average length of a word
- How many times each word occurs
- How many words start with each letter of the alphabet

I've got the code to do the first 2 things:

```
with open(input('Please enter the full name of the file: '),'r') as f:
     w = [len(word) for line in f for word in line.rstrip().split(" ")]
     total_w = len(w)
     avg_w = sum(w)/total_w

print('The total number of words in this file is:', total_w)
print('The average length of the words in this file is:', avg_w)
```

But I'm not sure on how to do the others. Any help is appreciated.

Btw, when I say "How many words start with each letter of the alphabet" I mean how many words start with "A", how many start with "B", how many start with "C", etc all the way through to "Z".

Comment: Look up If statements and check out Python dictionaries: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/how-to-use-dictionaries-in-python

Comment: First you should be extracting all the words, which you have done already in order to accomplish task 1 and 2 (actually you have stored the lengths, but it's straightforward to store the words instead). For task 3 I recommend you check out [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). Regarding task 4 I'm not 100% what you mean; did you mean words that start with *any* letter of the alphabet? In any case I have the feeling that the built-in function [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) is going to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this, a more advanced approach would involve an initial simple gathering of the text and its words, then working on the data with ML/DS tools, with which you could extrapolate more statistics (Things like "a new paragraph starts mostly with X words" / "X words are mostly preceeded/succeeded by Y words" etc.)

If you just need very basic statistics you can gather them while iterating over each word and do the calculations at the end of it, like:

```
stats = {
  'amount': 0,
  'length': 0,
  'word_count': {},
  'initial_count': {}
}

with open('lorem.txt', 'r') as f:
  for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    if not line:
      continue
    for word in line.split():
      word = word.lower()
      initial = word[0]

      # Add word and length count
      stats['amount'] += 1
      stats['length'] += len(word)

      # Add initial count
      if not initial in stats['initial_count']:
        stats['initial_count'][initial] = 0
      stats['initial_count'][initial] += 1

      # Add word count
      if not word in stats['word_count']:
        stats['word_count'][word] = 0
      stats['word_count'][word] += 1

# Calculate average word length
stats['average_length'] = stats['length'] / stats['amount']
```

Online Demo [here](https://repl.it/repls/BarrenOriginalExponents)

Answer (score 0):

> Interesting challenge you were given, i made a proposition for question 3, how many times a word occurs inside the string. This code is not optimal at all, but it does work.
>
> > also i used the file `text.txt`

edit: noticed i forgot to create wordlist as it was saved in my ram memory

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as doc:
    print('opened txt')
    for words in doc:
        wordlist = words.split()     

for numbers in range(len(wordlist)):
        for inner_numbers in range(len(wordlist)):
            if inner_numbers != numbers:
                if wordlist[numbers] == wordlist[inner_numbers]:
                    print('word: %s == %s' %(wordlist[numbers], wordlist[inner_numbers]))
```

> Answer to question four: This one wasn't really hard after you have created a list with all the words since strings can be treated like a list and you can easily get the first letter of the string by simply doing `string[0]` and if its a list with strings `stringList[position of word][0]`

```
for numbers in range(len(wordlist)):
        if wordlist[numbers][0] == 'a':
            print(wordlist[numbers])
```

Comment: I will also note that you wrote .split(" ") but .split() by default is spaces